# Fluent NHibernate "HasMany" classes in Configuration.ClassMappings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, fluent-interface

I'm trying to create a procedure to check the database structure, and for most of it I just look at "NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ClassMappings", but I can't find in the PersistentClass collection or each class properties the list of tables generated by fields mapped like this:

```
...
HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildrenListField);
...
```

How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what your are looking for are the `CollectionMappings`

```
foreach (var clazz in cfg.CollectionMappings)
....
```